# How to make emails look good on mobile?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have a newsletter application and I'm using the Roadie gem so that I can move the in-line styling to the header. However, the email doesn't look the greatest on mobile.

What's the best way to ensure that your email templates respond-well/look good on mobile devices with small screens?

Here's my template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>My Title</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
  body{font-family: 'cavier', 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;background: #eeeeee;}
  .container{width: 570px;margin: auto;padding: 40px 0;}
  .main {padding: 70px 100px;font-weight: 300;background: #fff;}
  .header{background: #cc0000;padding: 10px 0 5px 25px;min-height: 40px;}
  .logo{float: left;}
  .credo{color: white;font-style: italic;font-size: 12px;margin-left: 230px;margin-top: 10px;}
  .footer {background: #7e7e7e;text-align: center;color: #fff;font-weight: 100;padding: 15px 0;}
  .unsubscribe {text-align: center;color: #fff;font-weight: 100;padding: 15px 0;}
  .h8{font-size: 28px; font-weight: 300;}
  .red, .red a{color: #d93f3f;text-decoration: none;}
  div.text{font-size: 20px;color:#616161;margin-bottom: 5px;}
  .justify{text-align: justify;}
  .blue, .blue a{color: #3fb2ff;}
  .get_started{background: #66ccff;color: #fff;text-decoration: none;padding: 10px 30px;font-weight: 400;font-size: 22px;}
  .branding {color: white; font-weight: normal;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <%= image_tag 'logo.png', class: 'logo' %>
      <div class="credo">Credo here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main"><%= yield %></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise.

Comment: Any help here would be great. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's important to keep in mind:

1. Don't over design. Keep things simple, the more objects you create, the more chances for errors.
2. Better - Limit your design to a single column - maybe white spaces on both sides and a single column with your content.
3. Try this website. It shows you what your design looks like on different resolutions.

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/